# When is PessimisticLockException Thrown when using PessimisticLocking

Tags: jpa, pessimistic-locking

According to the docs, if a lock is attempted and the object is already a locked, the transaction will not be rolled back and a LockTimeoutException is thrown.

In what cases will a PessimisticLockException be thrown when using an EntityManager?